# Speed issue while appending strings

Tags: java, string, performance

Whenever I try to add the numbers in string like:

```
String s=new String();

 for(int j=0;j<=1000000;j++)

    s+=String.valueOf(j);
```

My program is adding the numbers, but  very slowly. But When I altered my program and made it like:

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();

for(int j=0;j<=1000000;j++)

sb.append(String.valueOf(j));
```

I got the result very quickly. Why is that so?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: May I suggest you to read Effective Java http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683

This book will cover basic knowledge of Java programming. If you have further question, you can still go back here, of course

Comment: It'll get faster still if you pre-size the StringBuffer:

`StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(5888896);`

Then it might get *slightly* faster again if you change to `StringBuilder`.

Incidentally, you can just use `sb.append(j);` to append the number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s+=String.valueOf(j);` needs to allocate a new `String` object every time it is called, and this is expensive. The `StringBuffer` only needs to grow some internal representation when the contained string is too large, which happens much less often.

It would probably be even faster if you used a `StringBuilder`, which is a non-synchronized version of a StringBuffer.

One thing to note is that while this does apply to loops and many other cases, it does not necessarily apply to all cases where Strings are concatenated using `+`:

```
String helloWorld = getGreeting() + ", " + getUsername() + "!";
```

Here, the compiler will probably optimize the code in a way that it sees fit, which may or may not be creating a `StringBuilder`, since that is also an expensive operation.

Comment: +1 for StringBuilder. You could also pre-allocate memory for it (parameter to the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

Because s += "string" creates a new instance. A String is immutable. StringBuffer or StringBuilder adds the String without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

In Java as in .NET Strings are immutable. They cannot be changed after creation. The result is that using the +operator will create a new string and copy the contents of both strings into it.

A StringBuffer will double the allocated space every time it runs out of space to add characters. Thus reducing the amount of memory allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, from the Javaspecialists newsletter by Heinz Kabutz:

http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue068.html

and this later article:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Interviews/community/kabutz_qa.html